# Why are the parameters i'm passing to the server with Alamofire undefined?

Tags: swift, alamofire, google-cloud-functions

I've got an http request from within swift to google cloud functions/node.js using alamofire:

```
 Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: [
            "api_version": apiVersion,
            ])
```

I know the request is hitting the server and executing the function on the server because i print out a log message that i'm in the function.

I also know that the apiVersion on the client contains data which is a stripe api version.

But on the server in this function:

```
exports.ephemeral_keys = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

console.log("activated ephemeral keys") // prints to the console

const stripe_version = req.query.api_version //is undefined
```

console.log(stripe_version) is logging undefined.

Any ideas?

****** Update  *********

I took a look at this post and I suspect there is an encoding issue but advice would be sweet.

[How to add Alamofire URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282281/how-to-add-alamofire-url-parameters)

Thanks.

Comment: If I see right, you are sending parameters in a POST body, but you're expecting query parameters.

Comment: So try to add encoding parameter to Alamofire's `request` function as mentioned in the link you provided.

Comment: I found the answer which was to change the line req.query.api_version  on the server in node to req.body.api_version. Thx though.

Comment: Yes, you either change iOS app or server behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```
Alamofire.request(url, 
                  method: .post, 
                  parameters: ["api_version": apiVersion], 
                  encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString))
```