# Alamofire 5 (Beta 6): Parameters of PUT Request do not arrive in Flask-Restful

Tags: python, swift, flask, alamofire

**UPDATE**
For me the Problem got fixed as soon as I was putting "encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)" in my request. Maybe this helps somebody else. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282281/how-to-add-alamofire-url-parameters)

I struggled the whole day to find the problem in my Alamofire PUT Request or the Flask Restful API. Request like GET, DELETE and POST are working fine with **Alamofire**, **except the PUT Request.** 
When I'm using PUT Requests in combination with **Postman** and **Flask-Restful** everything is also working fine. But as soon as I'm trying to achieve the same Result with **Alamofire**, I'm not getting any parameters in Flask. I tried to illustrate this in the code examples.

So in short my example illustrates the following:

**DELETE Request**(Same with GET and POST)

Postman: success

Alamofire: success

**PUT Request**

Postman: success

Alamofire: failure (parameter dictionary empty in Flask-Restful)

Here is my Python Code [API Server]:

```
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify
from flask_restful import Resource, Api, reqparse


app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)
class Stackoverflow(Resource):
    def delete(self):
        print(request.args)
        if request.args.get('test-key') is None:
            return jsonify({"message": "failure"})
        else:
            return jsonify({"message": "success"})

    def put(self):
        print(request.args)
        if request.args.get('test-key') is None:
            return jsonify({"message": "failure"})
        else:
            return jsonify({"message": "success"})

api.add_resource(Stackoverflow, '/stackoverflow')
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True, host='0.0.0.0')
```

If I'm using Postman, I get this result (like expected):
[Result in Postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wfAG.png)

But now I'm trying to do the same with Alamofire in Swift. Same Server, nothing changed.

SWIFT demo Code [IOS APP]:

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire
import SwiftyJSON

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view
        simplePUTRequest()
        simpleDELETERequest()

}

    func simplePUTRequest(){

        AF.request("http://localhost:5000/stackoverflow", method: .put, parameters: ["test-key":"testvalue"])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in

                if let data = response.data {

                    print("Result PUT Request:")
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    //print(utf8Text)
                }else{

                }
    }
    }

    func simpleDELETERequest(){

        AF.request("http://localhost:5000/stackoverflow", method: .delete, parameters: ["test-key":"testvalue"])
            .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
            .responseJSON { response in

                if let data = response.data {

                    print("Result DELETE Request:")
                    print(String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)!)
                    //print(utf8Text)
                }else{

                }
        }
    }
```

Xcode Console:

```
Result PUT Request:
{
  "message": "failure"
}

Result DELETE Request:
{
  "message": "success"
}
```

python Console (both Alamofire Requests):

```
ImmutableMultiDict([])
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2019 21:17:31] "PUT /stackoverflow HTTP/1.1" 200 -
ImmutableMultiDict([('test-key', 'testvalue')])
127.0.0.1 - - [15/Jun/2019 21:17:31] "DELETE /stackoverflow?test-key=testvalue HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

As you can see, I'm getting the success message only while using the DELETE method. 
Till now I tried using different encodings like URLEncoding.httpbody and URLEncoding.default, but nothing really helped. 
For me it seems like it's a Alamofire/Swift Problem, because in Postman the same request method is working fine. 
I would really appreciate your help, because I'm stuck and don't know anything further to do. I hope I didn't misunderstood something essential. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

I am currently using the same version AlamoFire, and when I use the PUT method, I use it as follows:

```
let request = AF.request(url, method: .put, parameters: ["uid": uid],
                         encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: headers)
request.responseJSON(completionHandler: { response in 
    guard response.error == nil else {
        //Handle error
    }
    if let json = response.value as? [String: Any]
    // Handle result.
}
```

The only difference to your post is that I used the encoding option. You can try to put the option and see what happens.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I'm not using JSON in the REST Api to get parameters yet, so that unfortunately doesn't work. But maybe I switch to it as a workaround, because I can't get it to work right now the other way. So your answer still helps :)

Comment: Wow.... you're awesome ... this solution helped me a lot thank you Seop Yoon

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your server is expecting your `PUT` parameters to be URL form encoded into the URL. You may be hitting the version of the `request` method that uses JSON encoding by default, so adding `encoder: URLEncodedFormParameterEncoder.default` at the end of your `request` call should fix that. A future release will make that the default, as it's safe across all request types.

If that's not the issue, I suggest you investigate more closely to see what the differences between the requests may be. Since you control the server you should have easy access to the traffic.

Comment: Thank you for answering. It clearly makes sense to me but unfortunately still doesn't work. I'm trying to investigate more like you said. Maybe I also switch to a different way to pass the parameters when using PUT requests as a workaround till I find a solution for this problem.

Comment: Thank you, in the end your answer helped me to find the missing piece to fix the problem. I searched for "query string Alamofire" and found another Stackoverflow question [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282281/how-to-add-alamofire-url-parameters) where somebody advised to put "encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString)" in the request. No it works perfectly. Thank you for giving me a new idea :)