# send json array to alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

```
product:[{"id":1,"qty":5,"price":5000},{"id":2,"qty":10,"price":7500}]
user_id:12
lon:112
lat:-7
lokasi:ada
tanggal:12-05-2019
```

How send that all parameter with Alamofire? Here is my attempt:

```
    let par : [String:Any] = [ "product": productItem,
                "user_id": myID(),
                "lon":data["longitude"] ?? "",
                "lat": data["latitude"] ?? "",
                "lokasi":data["location"] ?? "",
                "tanggal": data["tanggal"] ?? ""
      ]
    let header = [
                    "Accept":"application/json",
                    "Content-Type":"application/json"
                ]
        Alamofire.request("URL", method: .post,parameters: par,encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: header).responseJSON 
{ response in 

 }
```

I don't know what should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add Alamofire URL parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282281/how-to-add-alamofire-url-parameters)

Comment: what is the question/problem?