# Convert httpBody for x-www-urlencoded

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, alamofire

I'm doing a POST call to server but Alamofire always send the body as a JSON and not as a Form URL Encoded, I do know that in oder to encode the body I have to insert `data(using: .utf8, allowLossyConversion: false)`, but I don't know where.
How can I fix my code?

This is my actual code:

```
func asURLRequest() throws -> URLRequest {
    let url = try DBank.StagingServer.baseUrl.asURL()

    var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url.appendingPathComponent(path))

    // HTTP Method
    urlRequest.httpMethod = method.rawValue

    // Common Headers
    headers.forEach { (field, value) in
        urlRequest.setValue(value, forHTTPHeaderField: field)
    }

    // Parameters
    if let parameters = parameters {
        do {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: parameters, options: [])
        } catch {
            throw AFError.parameterEncodingFailed(reason: .jsonEncodingFailed(error: error))
        }
    }
```

Comment: I believe you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43282281/how-to-add-alamofire-url-parameters

Comment: @DevKyle Thanks man! how can I store the bearer token got from the httpResponse in the UserDefaults?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you have response handler like below:

```
Alamofire.request(url, method: .post, parameters: params, encoding: URLEncoding(destination: .queryString), headers: headers)
        .validate(statusCode: 200..<300)
        .responseString { response in

        //response.result.value will contain http response from your post call

}
```

With the result from this response you would set:

```
UserDefaults.standard.set("<result>", forKey: "<token>")
```